# C++ Behavior of priority_queue pop() and top() when queue is empty

Tags: c++

C++11.

If I try to `pop` off of an empty `priority_queue,` then I get a compile time error. Specifically,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<int> pq;
    int x = pq.pop();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

yields the compile-time error:

```
In function 'int main()': 7:20: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

I am surprised that this is a compile-time error and not a runtime error, but that is another discussion.

What I don't understand is why the `top` method wouldn't do the same thing. In fact, if we change `pop` to `top` the code actually compiles and runs (albeit with a bizzare output). Specifically,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<int> pq;
    int x = pq.top();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

This code compiles, runs, and exits normally, but produces no output! It literally prints nothing. I do not understand how that can be.

Here are my questions:

1. Is the behavior for `pop` and `top` defined if the `priority_queue` is empty? I don't see any mention of this condition [in the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/top).
2. How is there no output in the second case? `top` returns a constant reference. So it must be pointing at something. I would imagine that it simply interprets whatever piece of memory it is pointing to as an integer. But that doesn't seem to be happening. It seems like the integer is behaving something like a `nullptr`.

Comment: The [`pop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop) function doesn't work as you expect that is should. The error message is spot-on. And is has nothing to do with the queue being empty or not (which can't be detected by the compiler!).

Comment: And attempting to get a reference to an element that doesn't exist (with e.g. the [`top`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/top) function) leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You must always make sure that the queue is not empty before calling `top` (or `pop`).

Comment: I'm sorry but a RTFM is required here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop

Comment: Docs say the behaviour of `top` is equal to calling `front` method on underlying container. By default the underlying container is `std::vector`, and calling `front` on empty `std::vector` is UB.

Comment: The `pop` understanding was a dumb error. But I am confused by the UB comments

Comment: @YSC Your turn to translate RTFM into some friendly like Read the fine manual, or such now ;-)

Comment: Specifically, I thought that UB means that you don't know what you get in the variable `x`. But since the code runs and terminates normally, I assumed that x must have some value. What this value is should be undefined, but my understanding is that it must be pointing at SOME piece of memory.

Comment: It was not clear to me that UB behavior meant that, for instance, an integer might not even be interprettable as an integer after that point in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> int x = pq.pop();
> ```

`pop` returns `void`. It is ill-formed to assign `void` to a variable. As the error says:

> ```
>  void value not ignored as it ought to be
> ```

On the other hand:

> ```
> int x = pq.top();
> ```

It is well-formed to assign an integer to a variable.

> 1. Is the behavior for pop and top defined if the priority_queue is empty?

No. The behaviour is undefined (for `std::priority_queue<int>`. The behaviour may be defined for other underlying containers).

> 2. How is there no output in the second case?

The behaviour is undefined.

> Specifically, I thought that UB means that you don't know what you get in the variable x.

That's correct, but an incomplete description of UB. UB means that you cannot predict anything about the behaviour of the program.

Comment: I have seen cases, typically involving pointers, where clearly you can get really unexpected behavior. But that it happens in such a simple case really surprised me.

Comment: @bremen_matt [Happy reading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54120862/560648)! (Moral of the story: don't underestimate how _insanely, ridiculously, hugely complex_ is the mechanism that translates your source code to something that a computer can understand.)

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of calling [`std::priority_queue::top`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/top) on an empty `priority_queue` depends on the underlying container.

> Reference to the top element as if obtained by a call to `c.front()`

As your code showed, the default argument `std::vector` is used as the underlying container, and the behavior of calling [`std::vector::front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front) on empty container is undefined; which means anything is possible.

> Calling front on an empty container is undefined.

It's similar for [`std::priority_queue::pop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop), which will call [`pop_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) on the underlying container; for [`std::vector::pop_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) calling it on an empty container is UB too.

> Calling pop_back on an empty container is undefined.

At last, [`std::priority_queue::pop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop) returns nothing; that's why `int x = pq.pop();` won't work (as the error message tried to tell you).

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `priority_queue` incorrectly. [From the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop) on `pop()`:

> **Return value**
>   (none)

Yet you try to bind that to an integral variable. This is the same as

```
void f() {};

int n = f();
```

and doesn't make any sense. Furthermore, for

```
int x = pq.top();
```

we again conclude [from the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/top) that

> Reference to the top element as if obtained by a call to `c.front()`

So the behavior depends on the `front()` member function of the underlying container. In your example, that's the default one, `std::vector`, hence [from the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front):

> Returns a reference to the first element in the container.
>   Calling front on an empty container is undefined.

There you are in UB land, hence don't try to conclude anything from the output of your program.