# Stack push pop top function unusual results

Tags: c++11, stack

I first push into the stack and then pop from it. From the empty stack I cout stack.top() and it prints the element which I have pushed earlier. Why is it so??

```
        priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>>minHeap ;

        minHeap.push(1) ;
        minHeap.pop() ;
        cout << minHeap.top() ;
```

Why the output of this is 1??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Behavior of priority\_queue pop() and top() when queue is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54368314/c-behavior-of-priority-queue-pop-and-top-when-queue-is-empty)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you code correctly you are pushingg 1 to the stack and then popping it leaving the stack empty.  I suspect the `pop` function isn't clearing the element when the last item is deleted.

There is probably some function to see if the stack is empty which you should call before you print `top`.