# C++ placement new after memset

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, memset, placement-new

Suppose there's a struct whose constructor does not initialize all member variables:

```
struct Foo {
  int x;
  Foo() {}
}
```

If I memset some buffer to 0, use placement new on that buffer to create an instance of Foo, and then read x from that instance, is that defined behavior?

```
void bar(void* buf) {
  memset(buf, 0, sizeof(Foo));
  Foo* foo = new(buf) Foo;
  std::cout << foo.x; // Is this undefined behavior?
}
```

Comment: [Here is nice CppCon](https://youtu.be/IAdLwUXRUvg) showing how deep this rabbit hole is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As a supplement to the other answer:

On the off chance that anyone feels like handwaving this away as "*technically* undefined behavior, but safe enough for me", allow me to demonstrate how thoroughly broken the resulting code can be.

If `x` is initialized:

```
struct Foo {
  int x = 0;
  Foo() {}
};

// slightly simpler bar()
int bar(void* buf) {
  std::memset(buf, 0, sizeof(Foo));
  Foo* foo = new(buf) Foo;
  return foo->x; 
}
```

g++-11 with `-O3` produces the following:

```
bar(void*):
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], 0   <----- memset(buff, 0, 4) and/or int x = 0 
        xor     eax, eax             <----- Set the return value to 0
        ret
```

Which is just fine. In fact, it doesn't even exhibit whatever overhead one could hope to eliminate via in-place uninitialized construction. Compilers are *smart*.

In contrast to that,  when leaving `x` uninitialized:

```
struct Foo {
  int x;
  Foo() {}
};
// ... same bar
```

We get, with the same compiler and settings:

```
bar(void*):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi] <----- Just dereference buf as the result ?!?
        ret
```

Well, it's certainly *faster*, but what happened to the `memset()`?

The compiler figured that since we put an uninitialized `int` (aka junk) on top of the freshly memsetted memory, it doesn't even have to bother with the `memset()` in the first place. It can just "recycle" the junk that was there beforehand.

`anything -> 0 -> anything` collapses down to `anything` after all. So the function not altering the memory pointed at by `buff` is a reasonable interpretation of the code.

You can play around with these examples on godbolt [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/q4EYzdsKE).

Comment: Footnote: I *think* the compiler would have been within its right to just leave `eax` as is in the second case. But I can see how returning the value stored in the object's storage might be consistent with the additional aliasing safety gcc adds for grandfathered-in unions.

Comment: Another thing to play with: `Foo* foo = new (std::launder((Foo*)buf)) Foo;`.

Comment: @Evg Doesn't `std::launder` require an object to be already at that location? This "works" because the compiler has to assume this is the case (even though it's not), but I'm not sure this is formally well-defined, unless IOC kicks in somehow.

Comment: It does. But why it changes the generated assembly I can't say.

Comment: @Evg The name for `std::launder` in the standard is **pointer optimization barrier**. It forces the compiler to assume that the new `Foo` and `buf` do not alias eachother, despite it being patently obvious. So the memset() applies to `buf`, and the `Foo` construction applies to the new `Foo` pointer, and the compiler is forced to treat them as separate addresses.

Comment: And how does this explain setting `eax` to zero when `std::launder` is used? Looks quite the opposite.

Comment: @Evg I *think* this might just be what gcc does for unitialized ints without clearly defined provided storage: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Mo7exn4zq (but it could be a myriad other things of course)

Comment: But that zero is a zero from `memset`. Try `memset` with `1`.

Answer (score 12):

It is textbook undefined behavior. Member `x` is not initialized after the constructor, and reading uninitialized variable is undefined behavior.

The fact that this memory was previously filled with something else is irrelevant.

Comment: Reading non initialized variable is UB? This is not true at all. It will always work and never fail. The only thing that the variable's value is not defined (i.e. you can't assume that it will always be 0 or something else in such case).

Comment: @alagner, yes, not initialized after object lifetime begins. The constructor is called, but member variable is not initialized.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev you are quite wrong. Reading uninitialized variable is textbook undefined behavior.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev What do you mean it will always work?  UB doesn't mean fail to compile.  UB means you can't know what the behavior is going to be.  In this example placement new could initialize the buffer to some debug representation which means the value of `x` can be different across different implementations.  Also, there is the standard which straight up states it is UB: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic#indet-2

Comment: @SergeyA yeah right, my bad, I focused on the placement new part too much.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev - Well... up until your program crashes over one miserable bool... https://stackoverflow.com/q/54120862/817643

Comment: @PeteBecker I guess you’ve addressed the wrong person ;)

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev -- "undefined behavior" does not mean "something bad will happen". It simply means that the C++ language definition doesn't tell you what a program that includes that behavior will do. Typically, such a program will "work" just fine. Until you're giving a demo to your most important customer, when it will crash.