# Disable GCC simplification of expressions known at compile time

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

Suppose I have the following C line:

```
int a = 4 + 7;
```

When compiling this line, GCC will always produce something like `mov DWORD PTR [rbp-X], 0xb`, as the result of this computation is constant and known at compile time. Is there a way to disable this behaviour to have a mov 4, add 7 instead?

A quick search led me to the -O0 or -OG flags, but they turn off other kinds of optimizations, such as the fact that functions should be aligned in memory.

Comment: Why do you want to turn of this very specific optimization but not others?

Comment: The problem is that `int array[4+7]` has to work, and `#if 4+7==1`. . It's not really a simplification, as it is language rules.

Comment: I confess myself curious as well. This is one optimization I never heard complaints against.

Comment: As noted in the answer, even `-O0` doesn't disable this "optimization": https://godbolt.org/z/raGGz6En5

Comment: I'm wondering what GCC would do with `int a = 4 + (volatile int) 7;` though. I suspect that even at `-O2` it would have to respect the `volatile`. But that's a local change, not a global setting.

Comment: @MSalters Does `volatile` on a rvalue have any meaning in C? GCC still compiles it to the same code.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I was doing researches on MBAE (Mixed Boolean Arithmetic Expressions), which are pretty things like `for all (x, y), x + y = 2(~(x ^ y)) + 3(~x & y) + 3(x & ~y) - 2(~(x & y))`. The goal here was to hide a little bit better the operation effectued: if every `y` becomes a 7, a part of the obfuscation here disappear.

Comment: @Katoptriss: That sort of expressions may make sense in a specific theoretical CompSci framework, but C has its own rules for `_Bool` and assembly code has wildly varying ideas about bools (x86 and ARM have flag registers, for instance)

Comment: If you're actually using `_Bool` (or C++ `bool`), the ABI for most platforms allows compilers to assume the object-representation is a `0` or `1` byte. Having it be a `7` would be UB. [Does the C++ standard allow for an uninitialized bool to crash a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54125820).  Of course if you're just using `int`, that's fine.

Comment: But note that GCC `-O0` [won't do constant-propagation across statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point), so you can just do `register unsigned seven = 7;` or `register unsigned y = 7`.  (The `register` keyword makes code-gen less horrible at `-O0`, normally never use it.) It may still take advantage of the fact that every `y` will read the same value, whatever that is, unless you use `volatile unsigned y = 7`.  Then `y ^ y` will do two loads, not optimize to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to disable this behaviour to have a mov 4, add 7 instead?

No. Evaluation of elementary constant expressions is built into the compiler.

Comment: Understood, thank you. I guess I will have to write plain assembly instead of C if I want this specific effect.

Comment: ***Why*** would you ever want that specific effect?

Comment: @abelenky See my comment above.